# LINQ to SQL working foreign key table rows

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am new to LINQ to SQL, hence this question.

By default if I do a query for a row, does LINQ to SQL fetch all the foriegn key rows?

eg:

let us say I have 1->N relationship will 3 tables

Branch -N> Departments -N> Employees
If I query a brand row

```
Branch b = (
    from b in brachDataContext.Branches 
    where b.id = id 
    select b).ToList();
```

Does this fetch all the departments related to the branch row and the employees related to these departments?

If so, wont that be a huge object. each branch might have 10 departments and each department might have 1000 employees, and we might not need all the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq 2 SQL uses deferred execution by default, which means that your Departments will be fetched if you enumerate over that collection.

However, you can control whether they should be included in the initial query by setting the `context.LoadOptions` property like so

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Branch>(b => b.Departments);
context.LoadOptions = dlo;
... query ...
```

Check [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/04/19/understanding-linq-to-sql-6-working-with-deferred-execution.aspx) out for more info on deferred execution.

And also read up on the difference between IEnumerable and IQuerable and their behaviors. It is the key to understanding all Linq providers.

As a heads up, my experience is that Linq 2 Sql works for smaller projects and rapid development etc. If you have *anything* else in mind, consider moving to Entity Framework or NHibernate for a more feature complete experience.

Comment: in the default behaviour they are NOT loaded

Comment: So in the default behavior if linq2sql does a query in the database only when I access the departments in the branch object, like with a foreach, am i right? Again if I use this statement  foreach(Department d in branch.Departments), are these related department rows fetched in a single database call?

Comment: It depends on what you do but it happens often that you get a lot of calls to the DB. in these cases I recommend to use a profiler to see the SQL that is generated. But if you know you are going to need them anyway, it is better to use the LoadOptions

Comment: thanks for the info. Any good link where I can learn more about internal working of linq2sql?

Comment: They are not loaded initially, but will be loaded when you _iterate_ the dependent collection. Hence the term deferred execution. This is, as Pleun points out, usually really bad since you will end up with a query for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

> If so, wont that be a huge object.
>   each branch might have 10 departments
>   and each department might have 1000
>   employees, and we might not need all
>   the records.

```
Branch b = (      from b in brachDataContext.Branches      
                  where b.id = id      
                  select b).ToList();
```

The code you have given will cause the query to be executed every time that line of code is hit- getting ALL of the data and storing it in memory. This is becuase you are using .ToList()

Consider `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` - this will use lazy loading (if enabled) and should only get the data that is needed.

You might also want to consider using a SQL profiler to see exactly when a query is being run on the database.

Comment: `.Include(..)` is an EF feature and does not exist for Linq 2 SQL

Answer (score 0):

No linq-to-sql does Lazy loading unless you specify otherwise.

If you want to load the details as well, you can use Loadoptions on your datacontext.